# Tweaktool Keyboard "Additional Layout Options" not working

Tags: usb, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweaks

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 with Gnome. I am seeing new behavior which seems to have been introduced within the past couple of weeks. I have a couple custom keyboard settings configured in Tweaktool "Additional Layout Options". These settings work great.

I have a USB keyboard plugged into the machine. If I have the keyboard plugged in when I start my Gnome session, the customized keyboard layout options are correctly applied to the USB keyboard. If I unplug and reconnect the keyboard, the keyboard does will *NOT* have the customized keyboard settings.

If I restart my Gnome session (using Alt-F2 -> "r"), the customized settings are applied to the keyboard.

I think this behavior is something new. Before, I was able to unplug/reconnect my keyboard and it would apply my customized keyboard settings on reconnect. Is there anything I can do to force the application of the custom keyboard tweaks on USB keyboard reconnect?

Is anyone else able to reproduce this? I don't have any other machines with Ubuntu 20.04.1 to test with.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be happy to try and reproduce this, but there is not enough info. Could you please describe the steps I need to take to reproduce it? 'couple custom keyboard settings' needs clarification first. Are you using as PS/2 (purple mini-DIN connector) **and** an USB keyboard? Is your problem about keyboard layouts or plugging/unplugging?

Comment: @Adriaan I have created an Ubuntu bug to track this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1899206

To clarify your question, I'm currently using USB input devices which are plugged into a USB-C hub which is plugged into a USB-C port on my laptop -- no PS/2 device is involved. There are no problems with keyboard layouts. My issues are specifically with additional keyboard options selected in Tweaktool "Additional Layout Options" -- none of those options persist when the USB keyboard is unplugged/reconnected.

Comment: This might be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1902001

Comment: or this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298182/gnome-tweaks-reset-after-lock-screen/1307657#1307657