# Gnome tweaks reset after lock screen

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 20.10, gnome-tweaks

I am altering the keyboard configuration in Ubuntu 20.10 via

```
gnome-tweaks
```

and then, in Keyboard and Mouse/Additional Layout Options I set Alt/Win key behavior to "ctrl is mapped to Win and the usual ctrl keys", since I'm using a the mac magic keyboard.

[image]

This choice however is reset each time I lock the screen, so I have to keep resetting it.

Is there a way to fix this?

System details:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am using 20.10

Comment: I restarted this way by entering r as a command in the command box. I will restart the pc to see what happens.

Comment: Ok configuration resets again, so this has not fixed it.

Comment: What should I edit? I can see  im-launch and SSH keyring.

Comment: Just added a screen shot.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this? I have 3 keyboard settings. All of them gets reset after screen lock. I always have to go back and toggle off and on a setting to get all 3 setting to take effect again.

Answer (score 2):

This is a confirmed bug in mutter:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1899206

A fix has been released for 20.04 so try upgrading and checking the version:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade mutter
mutter --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically not the answer to your question because it does not fix "gnome-tweaks"...

but in a terminal try:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard options  "['altwin\taltwin:ctrl_win']"
```

to try to fix the problem you're trying to remedy...

Comment: Do I need to run this at startup i.e. each time?

Comment: @apkg ...you tell us

Comment: Ok, I will see if it resets. If it does, I will add it via cron

Comment: @apkg ...did it work at all? did it persist through a reboot? I am also curious for my own reasons, but I dont believe I have the right equipment to test it with.

Comment: I just checked and I think it did not!